# Как максимизировать количество запросов на удаленный хост с NestJS/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, ddos

Я хочу сделать сервис (в целях обучения) для закидывания ресурса какого-то большим количеством запросов, по типу такого: **GET example.com/someResource**

Я попробовал это:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  this.http.get('example.com/someResource').toPromise();
  // that's a NestJS so it's a HttpService of HttpModule (Obvservable, so we need to transform it to Promise using 'toPromise()')
}
```

Но похоже это не работает, потому что  запросы идут слишком долго и получается маленькое соотношение времени/количеству запросов (за 4 секунды всего 500 запросов, в тоже время на питоне около 1200 запросв в секунду можно выжать)
Как можно усовершенствовать это и отправлять больше запросов?
Помогите, пожалуйста, курсач горит))

Comment: Здесь вопросы принято задавать на русском языке.

Comment: Прошу прощения, сейчас перепишу

Comment: а зачем nest для нагрузочного тестирования?

Comment: `ab`, `curl`+`xargs` не катят?

Answer (score 0):

Подключите HttpModule, заинжектируйте HttpService и с него выполняйте запросы.
Запросы стоит отправлять таким образом

```
this.httpService.get('url')
```

никаких toPromise, then не нужно - оставьте всё как есть. Таким образом вы не будете дожидаться ответа от удаленного ресурса